# If value of certain cell is unchanged for certain time period, then cell color should be change

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am counting number of invoices from another sheet column to m2.
for example M2 is counting total number of invoices generated for "Riyadh Steel"

Now I just want to change the cell color M2 to red or any other if Riyadh Steel did not make any purchase from last 30 days. i.e. M2 value is not change from last thirty days.

Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please check the help here to learn what this site about and how to ask a question. Your question belongs on Superuser.com, not here.

Comment: @Usman Use conditional formatting....

Answer (score 0):

You need a cell with the date the data was entered, maybe insert a column between or next to your current data.

Then use conditional formatting. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". For the first cell (L2), the formula might be something like

```
=(now()-N2)>30
```

(assuming dates are in column N)

Then enter format details as desired, before copying the format down to the other cells.